# Credit Card Trip Delay/Interruption Insurance

Tags: travel-insurance-claim

two separate questions:

1)
My original flight was Dec 1st A->B->C.
Assuming the airline cancelled the flight today (Nov 5th) under a covered reason, and changed me to Dec 3rd A->B, Dec 4th B->C, thus causing a delay, would a typical credit card trip delay/interruption insurance cover my hotel/meal at B on Dec 3?

2)
Airline's reason given to me was "COVID19", does this fall under "delay of the flight was the result of strike by airline personnel, quarantine, civil commotion, hijack, natural disaster, inclement weather, mechanical breakdown or denied boarding due to overbooking"

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket? In which countries are A, B and C, and what country is the airline from? I would expect the airline, not the travel insurance, to cover hotels and meals between both flights in this case (though from a legal standing this would probably be debatable given the advance notice).

Comment: @jcaron, Same ticket. Avianca. Said would not cover due to "COVID policy".  Just want to know the general experiences are in this situation, no time/resources to really stir up a fight with either the card company or airlines. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

> would a typical credit card trip delay/interruption insurance cover my hotel/meal at B on Dec 3?

Impossible to say without reading the terms and conditions and specifically the exlusions of your specific insurance. They are all different, complicated and often full of loop holes that help the insurance to avoid paying claims. I'm guessing that the insurance will say that's this is the airlines responsibility and so they are not on the hook. "Finger pointing" is popular game that insurances like to play.

> does this fall under  .... ?

Again hard to say. The airline will certainly claim it's outside of their control and Covid has bee repeatedly accepted as "extraordinary circumstances" but to what extent that's a valid excuse will be ultimately be decided by the courts.

You do NOT need to accept the new schedule. You can simply cancel and get a full refund. However, if you do accept, the insurance is unlikely to pay since you booked this new itinerary "as is" and as long a it gets delivered as booked, it's hard to make an insurance case.